# Работа с mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Подскажите. Я кодил в большинстве случаях на php и в основном на yii2. Сейчас решил потихоньку вникать в c#. Так вот у меня возник вопрос как в c# работать с mysql? Основные принципы понятны, но не могу найти примеры как взаимодействовать с БД по принципу модели... В yii например для работы с БД есть класс model который наследуються от ActiveRecords за счёт чего не приходиться запросы писать ручками например что бы получить пользователей достаточно было написать user::find()->select('name')->asArray()->all();  и даный запрос мне возвращали все имена пользователей в виде массива(разумеется есть модель user в которой описаны все свойства и методы для работы с БД). Есть ли на c# что то подобное?  Очень удобно так работать, класс для взаимодействии с БД писать не охото))) ведь полюбому есть готовый инструмент.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: "...класс для взаимодействии с БД писать не охото..." его полюбасу написать придется, паттерн репозиторий называется.

Answer (score 2):

Для языка C# существует масса различных ORM для облегчения взаимодействия с БД:

1. [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)
2. [NHibernate](https://nhibernate.info/)
3. [Dapper](https://dapper-plus.net//?gclid=Cj0KCQiAiNnuBRD3ARIsAM8KmltENli8g2O8jj1bntXG8MsuHzcMLSnSWXQw1qoioon5aGZtJWcF_XkaAv30EALw_wcB)

К ним так же существуют различные коннекторы для подключения к MySQL/MariaDB

У dapper есть готовая реализация [репозитория](https://dapper.phnx47.net/)